# Android, OnAсtionListener, OnTouch, motionEvent.ACTION_MOVE не работает движение по оси Y

Tags: android

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
            @Override  
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {  
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {  
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
                        lastX = motionEvent.getX();  
                        lastY = motionEvent.getY();  
                        return true;  
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  
                        float dx = motionEvent.getX() - lastX;  
                        float dy = motionEvent.getY() - lastY;  
                        actualX = prevX + dx;  
                        actualY = prevY + dy;  
                        defLayoutParams.leftMargin = (int) actualX;  
                        defLayoutParams.topMargin = (int) actualY;  
                        this.setLayoutParams(defLayoutParams);  
                        prevX = actualX;  
                        prevY = actualY;

                        return true;  
                }  
                return false;  
            }  
        });  
    }
```

где this - то что я хочу двигать пальцем по экрану.

Comment: @amoonfaber, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Благодарю за формат